# Evaluating $\int \frac{z^d f(z)}{z-a}\, dz$ over a closed contour.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

We know that for $z \in \mathbb{C}$

$$ \int_C \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\ dz = f(a) $$

where $C$ is a closed contour.

Then how can we compute

$$ \int_C \frac{z^d f(z)}{z-a} dz $$

Comment: You're missing a couple of assumptions: $f$ is analytic on the region enclosed by the contour, and $a$ is within the contour. Also, the contour is integrated counterclockwise.

Comment: You're also missing a factor of $2\pi i$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(z)=z^d f(z)$.  Then 
$$\int_C \frac{g(z)}{z-a}dz = 2\pi i \cdot g(a) = 2\pi i \cdot a^d f(a)$$

assuming that $C$ is a closed, positively oriented, rectifiable curve with winding number $n=1$, enclosing the point $z=a$, and that $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the region enclosed by $C$.